# How to replace content with open popup model content to new popup model

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used for two popup like “Launch first” and “Launch second “.

When i click to open “Launch first” popup we have option to open “launch second” popup also.

I need when I click on  “launch second” popup the “launch first” popup closed and “launch second” popup content load in “launch first” div.

**HTML File:**

```
<a href="first.html" data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch First</a>
    <a href="second.html" data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch Second</a>

    <div class="modal fade hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS File:**

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
  $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```

**Example Link :**

http://plnkr.co/edit/oZ304D7oPDKygDG05EWa?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 $('.modal-footer .btn').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

        $('.modal-body').load('second.html');
        $('.modal-footer .btn').hide();
    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FqAvP9ZRpiybigiNc5oj?p=preview

Comment: i need only replace content no need to open new popup

Comment: @ madalin ivascu : i need to pass ajax response . it's Work or Any changes needed?

Comment: how to load ajax response here?